# How to manage 'startActivityForResult' and 'ActivityResult' in both (A,B) activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I have two activities A and B.
From A, I am sending some data to B through `startActivityForResult` and getting response back from B in `ActivityResult`.
Now, what if I want to process what ever B sent to me and then send back data to B, do I have to use `startActivityForResult` and `ActivityResult` in B as well.

It's chat (back and forth) kind of a communication between A and B.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can `sendBroadcast` solve problem?

Comment: you can call `setResult()` in activity B and pass data in to intent and handle it `startActivityForResult` in Activity A

Comment: thanks for the help but what i am trying to achieve is:

A send data to B...... 
B send data back to A..... 
A send data back again to B after some process

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote the code which uses `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to send data between `activities`
**Activity A:**

```
    public class A extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        // Registering LocalBroadcastReceiver to receiver data from B
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiverA, new IntentFilter("activity_a"));
        findViewById(R.id.btnStartB).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                i.putExtra("key_string", "Value"); // add stuffs to be sent to Activity B
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to unregister receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiverA);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiverA = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get data from Intent, which we got from Activity B
            if (intent.hasExtra("key_string"))  {
                Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("key_string"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Here you can process the data, and send result to Activity B
                // Adding delay temporary, so that Toast will be visible on by one
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent("activity_b");
                        i.putExtra("key_string", "Value Of String From A");
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
                    }
                }, 600);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Activity B:**

```
public class B extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        // Registering LocalBroadcastReceiver to receiver data from A
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiverB, new IntentFilter("activity_b"));

        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent("activity_a");
                i.putExtra("key_string", "Value Of String From B");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(B.this).sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to unregister receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiverB);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiverB = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get data from Intent, which we got from Activity B
            if (intent.hasExtra("key_string"))  {
                Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("key_string"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: thanks for the help but what i am trying to achieve is:

A send data to B...... 
B send data back to A..... 
A send data back again to B after some process

Comment: and below is my code

activity A
----------

Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}

----------
activity B
----------

Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();

Comment: Yes. `mReceiverA` is exactly doing the same. Once you get data from `Activity B`, process it and send the result back to A via another broadcast. Do one thing! Make Two classes as I mentioned above and You'll understand the whole process. Believe me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent yourFirstAct= new Intent(firstAct.this,second.class);
yourFirstAct.putExtra("","");
startActivitForResult(yourFirstAct);
```

in first Activity,

```
public void onAcitivityResult(....){
 super();
}
```

in your second activity when you done,

```
Intent yoursecAct= new Intent();
yourSecAct.putExtra("","");
setResult(yourSecAct);
finish();
```

if you do startActivityResult() in fragment means,

your fragment mainActivity must return super() in

```
   public void onAcitivityResult(...){super()}
```